# OpenXML Replace text place holder with an image

Tags: openxml

Searching around and still not sure how to do this correctly.
I can insert an image into a document at the end but I need to have it replace a text place holder and insert the image at that location.

Comment: what is the question exactly? Is replacing the text a problem you're solving or the way you wish to do it?

Comment: Locating the location of the text and inserting the image at that location is the issue

Comment: Do you need to replace a single text place holder, or any text that fits something?

Comment: Is this using the openxml-sdk, or some other environment?

Comment: I would be replacing text so I would have something like {HOLDER}, that would be removed and replaced with the image.

Comment: Yes I am using Microsoft's OpenXML SDK